# Java: arrays of objects not working like non-arrayed objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, jframe

I'm writing a program using JGrasp, where tile is a class. The Following code compiles:

```
        tile ext = new tile();
        ext.assignValues(0);
        g.setColor(ext.color);
        g.fillRect(10+20, 35+20, 20, 20);
```

But the following does not:

```
        tile[][] ext = new tile[1][1];
        ext[0][0].assignValues(0);
        g.setColor(ext[0][0].color);
        g.fillRect(10+20, 35+20, 20, 20);
```

Am I initializing the 2D array wrong, or am I misunderstanding how arrays work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ext[0][0]` not initialized  as  `tile[][] ext = new tile[1][1];` is Array of  `instances of tile` (`Object` In general term)  but you have to initialize every object stored at array index before using those objects as default value is `null` for every element here.

```
tile ext[0][0]= new tile(); //Have to initialize it first 
//And than use it in your code
```

As I think you won't get anny issue during compilation but it will throw `NullPointerException` while you execute your code which is trying to manipulate `null` value.

Answer (score 3):

You have initialized the array `ext[][]`, but you have not initialized the `tile` in position `[0][0]`. Therefore it is empty, and trying to call a method would be like accessing a method of a null value.

```
tile[][] ext = new tile[1][1];
ext[0][0] = new tile();
ext[0][0].assignValues(0);
g.setColor(ext[0][0].color);
g.fillRect(10+20, 35+20, 20, 20);
```